# how to replace ios app with flutter app in app store

Tags: flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

We have already made an iOS app and have been running it for a year. Then last month, I decided to make a hybrid app using Flutter, and now it's just around the corner.

Is it possible to release a new plutter app with a bundle ID of an existing iOS app? If it is currently 1.2.8 version of iOS app, and the new plutter app is deployed in 1.2.9 version, can existing app users of 1.2.8 version use it without any problems even if no update?

If impossible, should we run 2 apps until all users download new apps? Actually, the two are the same app, but will apple pass through the app store?

I am very confused. please help me.

I couldn't find it even though I searched.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem a few months ago and here is my experience

You will need to support both versions until you have all ( or most ) of your users migrated to the new version. Because users won't update instantly and this will take some time.

Uploading a new version of the app with a different technology however is not a problem. The only issue would be depending on the way you have implemented user login, all of the users logged in with the previous version could be logged out and would have to login again, which is not great user experience.